# Once every 2 seconds, move the object to random coordinates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my `enemy` to move to a random X position between -2.4 and 2.4 every 2 seconds, but he moves in jerks and for a very small distance. I suspect that the problem is in `speed * Time.deltaTime`, but I don't know how to fix it

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Random=UnityEngine.Random;

public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform enemy;
    private float random;
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 10f;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(MoveEnemy());
    }

    IEnumerator MoveEnemy()
    {
        while (!MainGame.lose)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

            random = Random.Range(-2.4f, 2.4f);
            Debug.Log(random);
            enemy.transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(enemy.position,
                new Vector3(random, enemy.position.y),
                speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it moves too small steps, make the random range bigger? Moving -2.4 towards an enemy sounds like moving away. I don't know what `Time.timedelta` is, but if this action happens every 2 seconds, maybe you don't want to consider time at all and remove `* Time.timedelta` completely.

Comment: @ThomasWeller If I remove `* Time.deltaTime` then it moves in the range I need, but it just disappears and reappears elsewhere without moving

Comment: So, you're saying there should be a smooth transition, something like it glides to that position? In that case you probably want to store the destination somewhere and have it move towards that position in small steps. IDK how that's done in Unity, but it seems to require a bunch of additional code

Comment: @ThomasWeller far as I know, just this function is performed by `* Time.deltaTime`, but in the coroutine it does not work correctly, for some reason

Comment: Sorry, this is too much to explain for me. I hope you get an answer from someone who has Unity3D installed on his machine and can give you concrete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are moving the enemy only once every two seconds. To me it sounds like you rather want to constantly move the enemy but only choose a new target position every 2 seconds so e.g.

```
// you can directly make Start a Coroutine by changing its return type 
IEnumerator Start()
{
    while (!MainGame.lose)
    {
        var random = Random.Range(-2.4f, 2.4f);
        var targetPosition = new Vector3(random, enemy.position.y);

        for(var time = 0f; time < 2f; time += Time.deltaTime)
        {
            // need to check within here since otherwise it would always try to finish the for loop
            if(MainGame.lose) 
            {
                // quits from this entire routine
                yield break;
            }

            enemy.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(enemy.position, targetPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);

            // this basically means continue in the next frame
            yield return null;

            if(enemy.position == targetPosition) 
            {
                // quits the for loop and basically starts again from var random = ...
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So for up to two seconds you try to reach this random target with a constant linear movement and you select a new random target position if you either exceed 2 seconds or reached the target before that